# iOS Video Frame taking priority over fixed header

Tags: ios, css, mobile, fixed

Sorry for the badly worded title, it's hard to summarise this.

I've got a fixed header at the top of my website, and then I've got some videos that are iFramed in (from Vine and YouTube mostly). My problem is that even though the header is fixed, with a higher z-index, and it's APPEARING higher than the video iFrames, it's not behaving that way. This seems to be due to the iOS Video frame, or whatever you want to call it.

I've put this mock together to show you what I mean:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/324723/Web/vid_iframe_fixed_issue.html

Expected behaviour is - Scroll down, then tap on the header while it's overlapping some text. The header text has an anchor hover tag, so it'll turn black. This is what should happen.

Refresh, then scroll the page down until the header overlaps the first video (Vine), then try and click on the header, over where the video should be (say the letter "A"), it'll load up the video.

Refresh, then scroll down the page until the header overlaps the second video (YouTube), and try again: it'll work properly, because YouTube has a splash screen. However, if you then load the YouTube video, click 'Done' to get out of the video, and repeat this process, you'll have the same issue as with the Vine video, because the splash screen is gone and the iOS Video frame has replaced it. Vine has no splash screen, so this issue is apparent immediately.

Why is it displaying the header above the videos, but still prioritising the video on tap? This is only an issue with iOS, Android seems fine. Am I doing something wrong, or is this an inherent issue with iOS?

edit: This is an issue on other sites too (see Mashable or Instagram). I'm not so sure there's a way around this.